# practically most used background colors in web design

Tags: background-color, web

I'm customizing a color picker's default showing colors which will be used as background colors. I'm wondering if there is a collection of the colors that are particularly useful in practical web design. Like nobody(hopefully) would use #f00 as a 100%-width page's background color while #fff is a universally usable one, there's DO'S and DONT's when it comes to picking background colors. So what are the candidates in your opinion?

I know this could be subjective, but generally I believe there IS a solid set of them.

[edit] : I kinda have an idea to customize the color picker in a logic way, first pick a buch of hues, them for each hue, start from the possible lightest of saturation to the possible heaviest. A bit demenstration:

gray   [ #eee, #ccc, #ddd, .... ]

green  [ ... .... ... .... ]

blue   ....

yellow

brown [

Comment: http://www.websitecolorscheme.com

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As for a realistic answer, `#fff` won the race, right? Sometimes you'll see shades of gray, `#eee`, `#eaeaea`, and an occ. `#000`.

If you want to mix things up, I'd recommend checking out http://kuler.adobe.com/ to get an idea for what's popular, but perhaps slightly different. It's fun to experiment with the palettes up there.

Comment: Kuler looks like a colorlovers ripoff

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is a universal standard for picking up colors for your site. It entirely depends on the nature of the site and the kind of users that visit the site.

For eg: it would be nice to give a greenish color for a site that's theme is nature.

Here is a nice site in which you can choose color combinations and get a preview of that in a single click.

[Color Scheme Designer](http://colorschemedesigner.com/)

Never choose a color that will distract the user from seeing the actual contents of the site.

If you allow users to select the color then it would be nice to show them a preview of the site with the colors they have chosen.

Comment: So the better idea will be to give them a preview of the site with their chosen colors.

Answer (score 2):

Contrast is what really matters when choosing background/foreground colours, so they're likely to be very light, or very dark

so you'll need light and dark variants. i'd probably opt for:

light red, orange, yellow, green, blue, indigo, violet

and dark as above

maybe the same for some earthy type tones, browns, greys, etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you like colours like I do, you might visit [ColourLovers](http://www.colourlovers.com/).  They've got some great ways of choosing colours, and colour schemes.  The [website trends](http://www.colourlovers.com/trends/websitecolors) section might be interesting to you.

I personally like schemes where the lighter colour is not pure white.  Pure white can be sometimes harsh when reading lots of text.

Answer (score 2):

1. Creativity is BREAKING the rules.

It is possible that a seemingly bad color combination, if used in right proportions, can actually look good, so there is no such thing as a bad color combination, it also matters on the shades, difference in colors.

Believe it or not, i own a site ([www.salvin.in](http://www.salvin.in)) where user can change the background color to many different choices and it still manages to look good *ahem in most of the cases.

There are a few things that i suggest you to look into:

1. Color wheel
2. Color harmonies
3. Triads and Tetras
4. Mono chromes (with contrasting shades)
5. Complimentaries

Comment: I tried out your site. Yes it works. You selected the set of low-saturation colors as background candidates. That means you did follow certain rules when you made those decisions - which colors can and which can't be in the right-side color panel. There's is some kind of RULE. As said try #f00 or #0f0, that won't look any prettier ;=)
I'm no expert on color harmonies, I'm basically more fond of coding instead of designing. My purpose here is actually quite simple, to find a generally usable background colors.

Comment: Good observation, Yes i have carefully choosen those colors.
But i feel you have misinterpreted me. I said Combination + proportions. In my site, Black (actually dark gray) is the most Dormant color, more than 40% of it is in Black (if you open several 'windows'), So, with Respect to that Proportion, i made a choice of colors.
Surely the choices would have changed if Black was not Dormant.
Which Again leads to the point thre is no such thing as a bad combination. the shades and proportions matter too.

Comment: another example is that i was always of the believe that red would never match with orange
but this site proved me wrong :http://www.wolframalpha.com , so you see, thre is no rule. its just creativity

Answer (score 0):

I find that #000 messes up my eyes.  After looking at mainly #FFF pages/applications, then switch to #000, then when I go back to anything else, it take a while for my eyes to adjust.  I vote "no" to #000.

Comment: Blizzard.com works great with #000 as a full page bg. Silver(ish) and blue(ish) elements looks pretty cool on #000;

Comment: that is very very specific to environment. u cannot rule out black just because its difficult for YOU to switch to another site :)
very lame escuse by the way :)